# Zend - Accessing datas from form from another controller by a view helper

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, controller

after some questions about how to resolve one of my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609611/using-several-modules-in-the-same-view) I have another one.

I made a form in a view helper because I needed to access the result of this form in another controller.

So here is my view helper called QuickSearch.php

```
class Zend_View_Helper_QuickSearch extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function quickSearch()
    {
    $form = new Application_Form_QuickSearchForm();
    return $form;
    }
}
```

calling QuickSearchForm.php

```
class Application_Form_QuickSearchForm extends Zend_Form
```

{

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod('post');
    $this->setAction('/search/quicksearch');
    $this->addElement('text', 'searchLocation', array(
            'label' => 'Location:',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array('StringToUpper')
            ));
    //[some other elements]
    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Search',
    ));
}
```

In my main page view, I call the viewhelper with

```
echo $this->quickSearch();
```

Which works, since I have access to my form.

When I submit my form, the /search/quicksearch is called as it's supposed to be but when I try to access the data from the form, it seems that it's empty.

Here is my Search controller (SearchController.php)

```
class SearchController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function quicksearchAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_QuickSearchForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        echo("post");
        $data = $form->getValues();
        echo($data['searchLocation']);
    }

}
```

}

I put the echo("post") to see if I was getting a POST request, and every time it works.
the only thing that display is the 'post' and the second echo doesn't display anything.

I don't know what I didn't understand in the way to get the form's data from another controller.

Can someone help me with this ? I just don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the post data to the form object. The typical way to do this is by calling the `isValid()` method of the form (which also validates the submitted data):

```
public function quicksearchAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_QuickSearchForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            $data = $form->getValues();
            echo $data['searchLocation'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seeing the solution I realised that I never indicated that I wanted to get the POST request ...
Now, everything works perfectly.
Thanks again !